# Google cloud billing renewal process

Tags: google-compute-engine, cloud, google

I have a server hosted in Google Cloud which still is using the 300$ Google gives you for testing purposes on new accounts but it is ending soon. I alredy have a credit card assigned to my billing dashbord but I don´t want to lose anything in this server when this 300$ end, will it automatically begin to bill from my account once this test is over? Or do I have to do anything else to do so?

Comment: Google will automatically begin using the payment method assigned to the Payment Account. However, some payment methods (credit cards) have problems. Try making a manual payment using that card. https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/manual-payment If there is a payment problem, Google will notify you via email so that you can correct the problem. Be sure to check for SPAM folder for Google emails.

Comment: @JohnHanley I will add some balance to my account from my main credit card and also a secondary card, known as backup credit card by Google. Thanks